# RabbitMQ : configuration file not found

Tags: linux, rabbitmq

My rabbitmq-env.conf looks like :

```
root@encoder001 /etc/rabbitmq# cat ./rabbitmq-env.conf 
CONFIG_FILE=/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
```

when I restart , the log said :

```
=INFO REPORT==== 16-Sep-2017::09:22:21 ===
node           : rabbit@encoder001
home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
config file(s) : /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config (not found)
cookie hash    : r6Fx293RnLUql2MqE0Wfqg==
log            : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@encoder001.log
sasl log       : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@encoder001-sasl.log
database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@encoder001
```

In fact , the file is there .. and I'm prettysure it have proper access flags

```
root@encoder001 /etc/rabbitmq# ls -la |grep config
-rw-r--r--  1 root rabbitmq 22994 Sep 16 09:16 bunnies.config
-rw-r--r--  1 root rabbitmq 22994 Sep 16 08:58 rabbitmq.config
```

I also tried to change to 'CONFIG_FILE=/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq' , but the server can not start.

Kindly please give me any clue to fix it.

Comment: Which version of rabbitmq arer you using?

Comment: How did you install rabbitmq?

Comment: @MartinSchröder : it's 3.6.11 .

Comment: @ItaiGanot I installed it per https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked up on Google how to use the configuration file of RabbitMQ and found [this official article](https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html).

According to that article, the directive should be prefixed with "RABBITMQ_":

```
RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE
```

Rather than

```
CONFIG_FILE
```

I'd try that and see how it works.

Comment: I tried 'RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE=/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq' per that document, and rabbit fail to start. I put the sysctl status at https://pastebin.com/1d1ujtZf

Comment: @BinoOetomo, add the file a .conf extension, update the `rabbitmq-env.conf` file and try restarting the service.

Comment: @ltai Ganot. I apologize for this late response. I try also that combination but rabbit still failed with Oct 17 06:50:00 ngeweb rabbitmqctl[6287]: /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmqctl: 1: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf: CONFIG_FILE: not found

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .config extension such that you have CONFIG_FILE=/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq

Answer (score 0):

I did entry as "RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILES=/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq" on rabbitmq-env.conf file then created "rabbitmq.config" file and gave 777 permission to it. so that worked for me. The rabbitmq is taking by default extension as .config so if we mention rabbitmq.config on rabbitmq-env.conf file also then on logs the name is getting differ so getting above error.